# Runtime: Instance methods vs classmethods (Python)

Tags: python, performance, runtime, static-methods, class-method

I am interested in the runtime difference between *instance methods* and *classmethods* in Python.

## Problem

I have a file *main.py* which loops through the lines of a file (more than 1 million lines).
There are several methods that get called for each line.
I outsourced these methods in another file *line.py* within a class *LineStuff*.
Now I import LineStuff in *main.py* and call several methods for each line.

Since LineStuff does not need to have any states I first implemented all the methods as *classmethods *(class variables are needed, i.e. *staticmethod* would not work).

But a simple test (see below) suggest that using classmethods is actually slower.

Question: Is that actually the case and if yes, why is that?

## Test

For the purpose of testing I created a file *main.py* that runs the imported methods and measures the runtime of each approach.
In the file *line.py* there are a class for *instance methods*, *classmethods *and *staticmethods *respectively, which just calculate the square of a given number.

### main.py

```
from line import Standard, Class, Static
import timeit

def runtime(classtype:str, cnt:int = 10000000, value:int = 1000):
    
    start = timeit.default_timer()

    if classtype == "standard":
        x = Standard()
        for _ in range(cnt):
            x.method(1000)
    elif classtype == "class":
        for _ in range(cnt):
            Class.method(1000)
    elif classtype == "static":
        for _ in range(cnt):
            Static.method(1000)
    
    end = timeit.default_timer()
    
    return round(end - start, 2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    runtimes = {
        "standard": runtime("standard"),
        "class": runtime("class"),
        "static": runtime("static"),
    }
    
    print(runtimes)
```

### line.py

```
class Standard:
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
    
    def method(self, number):
        return number ** 2
    
    
class Class:
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
    
    @classmethod
    def method(cls, number):
        return number ** 2
    
    
class Static:
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
    
    @staticmethod
    def method(number):
        return number ** 2
```

### Result

The output yields:
`{'standard': 2.58, 'class': 4.02, 'static': 3.25}`